# How do I categorise non-english email using procmail and command line tools?

Tags: email, command-line-interface, text-classification, non-english, procmail

I am subscribed to a mail list where some of the messages are non-english which I cannot understand.

How do I filter the non-english messages to `/dev/null` using `procmail` and/or command line tools?

I use `procmail` to filter my email, so ideally any alternative tool would also require a `procmail` recipe.

I'd prefer not to have to train my own language models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the perl [TextCat](https://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/TextCat/) package from [Gertjan van Noord](https://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/).

The `text_cat` script outputs the most likely language for the mail.  This recipe assumes `text_cat` has been installed under `/usr/local/bin`.

Here is a simple `procmail` recipe to call the `text_cat` script:

```
:0
* ^Subject.*Jobs.*Board
{
    LANG_=`/usr/local/bin/text_cat`

    :0
    * ! LANG ?? ^english$
    /dev/null

    :0
    jobs/
}
```

I've been running text_cat for a few years.  There haven't been any non-english messages classified as english, that is, no false-positives.  I've not been rigorous about checking for false-negatives.

---

A second way, as mentioned by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) in a comment, is to use the language categorisation provided by [spamassassin](https://spamassassin.apache.org/) which also uses the text_cat script.  Spamassassin will unwrap any MIME transfer encodings which the vanilla text_cat version above won't.

Here is an **incompletely tested** `procmail` recipe for filtering on the spamassassin `X-Spam-Languages` header:

```
:0
* ^Subject.*Jobs.*Board
{    
    # Delete non-english language emails using spamassassin header
    # Test for not X-Spam-Languages: en
    :0
    * !^X-Spam-Languages: en$
    foreign/

    # Save english language mails in folder
    :0
    jobs/
}
```

**Warning:** spamassassin will occasionally provide multiple language categorisations like so:

```
X-Spam-Languages: en da ro
```

which the above recipe does not account for.

**Spamassassin Language Categorisation Configuration**

Edit `/etc/spamassassin/v310.pre` and uncomment the following line:

```
loadplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::TextCat
```

Configure the plugin in `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`:

```
ok_languages en       # I understand english
inactive_languages '' # Enable all languages
add_header all Languages _LANGUAGES_
# score UNWANTED_LANGUAGE_BODY 5 # Increase score - not necessary and not recommended
```

This recipe was incompletely tested with spamassassin version 3.4.2.

---

To adapt these answers to excluding a different language would involve substituting the other language for `english` in the first case and substituting the other 2 character language code for `en` in the second case.

Comment: Keep in mind that the models which TextCat ships with are pretty crude, and don't do a good job of distinguishing between e.g. Danish and Norwegian or Serbian and Russian. There are other language identification tools with a similar interface, or you could train your own TextCat models.

Comment: Good to know, but I'm interested in english versus everything else.  I'd prefer not to have to train my own models (I've updated my question accordingly).

Comment: Another problem is that TextCat by itself knows nothing about email encodings. You might prefer to use a mail-aware filter like SpamAssassin, which includes an integrated fork of TextCat, but also takes care of unwrapping any MIME transfer encodings before running it.

Comment: I've been running text_cat for a few years.  There haven't been any non-english messages classified as english.  I've not been rigorous about checking the reverse case.

Comment: A procmail recipe using the SpamAssassin text_cat header would be useful and potentially something I'd accept.

Comment: `formail -A` is not necessary just to evaluate the value of `$LANG`.

Comment: @xebeche Your probably correct.  The man page suggests `formail -a` would suffice but I've not tested it.

Comment: @makeyourownmaker That's not what I meant. Procmail has the syntax `variablename ??` to test the values of variables. Cf. manpage procmailrc(5).

Comment: @xebeche I understand what your saying now.  Feel free to edit the answer.  I'd need to run some tests before making any changes.  Good point.  Thanks.

Comment: Credit should go to tripleee for making the simplifying edit suggested by xebeche.

Answer (score 1):

Many modern email clients identify the character set of the email message, though not usually its language. If you want to discard Japanese, Chinese, Korean, and Russian messages, you could try something like

```
:0HB
* ^Content-type:[  ]*text/[/;]*;[  ]*charset="?(iso-2022|ks-c|gb|koi|cp-1251)
foreign
```

Because some clients forget to change the character set when they write in English, this is likely to produce some false positives, so I recommend saving to a folder and reviewing it periodically. The opposite problem is harder; many foreign languages use the same character set as English, and thus can't be identified like this with any reliability.

Comment: This is a useful answer (I've upvoted), but given the limitations you list I'm inclined to accept my answer (assuming that is possible and only if there are no better answers within a week or two).

Comment: You can accept your own answer after a while (IIRC two days) and later change the accepted answer if anything better comes up. I agree at this point that yours is the better answer. Adapting it to use SpamAssassin should be reasonably trivial.

Comment: I've added some pointers for configuring language categorisation with spamassassin.  And I've adapted my earlier procmail recipe to use the spamassassin languages header.